# Can we use this.props.map as well as this.props.navigation in single class to navigate to another screen

Tags: javascript, java, react-native

I have used `this.props.maps` as well as `this.props.navigation` which is showing an error:

> this.props.navigation.navigate is undefined object

Trying to navigate to another page by rendering the firebase database but getting error but the same code i tried  by simple creating a view and navigating to another page then it is working

```
export default class ItemComponent extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // need to bind `this` to access props in handler
    this._onEditLibrary = this._onEditLibrary.bind(this);
  }

  static propTypes = {
      items: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };
  _onEditLibrary=()=> {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('EditLibrary');
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.itemsList}>
          <TouchableOpacity  onPress={this._onEditLibrary}>
        {this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <View key={index}>

                <ImageBackground source={item.Image} style={ { height:150, width:150}}>
                    <Text style={styles.itemtext}>{item.Name}</Text>
                    </ImageBackground>

                </View>
            )
        })
        }
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Need to navigate to another page

Comment: How are you using `ItemComponent`? `this.props.navigation` is only available if `ItemComponent` is a screen of a navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
export default class ItemComponent extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // need to bind `this` to access props in handler
    this._onEditLibrary = this._onEditLibrary.bind(this);
  }

  static propTypes = {
      items: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };
  _onEditLibrary=()=> {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('EditLibrary');
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.itemsList}>
        {this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={this._onEditLibrary}>
                    <ImageBackground source={item.Image} style={ { height:150, width:150}}>
                           <Text style={styles.itemtext}>{item.Name}</Text>
                    </ImageBackground>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')  showing the same error as before

Comment: I fixed that issue by myself just changed the  props to state and it worked anyway thanks for the support {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {